# How to prevent btrfs compressing /var

Tags: btrfs, compression

I just installed new instance of Fedora 33 and enabled compression for my root volume via `compress=zstd:3` mount option. I enabled compression of `/usr` with `chattr +x /usr`.

I would like to disable compression for `/var` directory and according to https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)#FILE_ATTRIBUTES I should be able to use `chattr +X /var` but the tool from F33 does not understand this option. In https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression there is a command `btrfs property set /var compression ""` however I am not able to tell if this works or not. Any file on my filesystem has no "compression" property set, this does not make sense.

I am assuming that btrfs automatically compresses all files by default when mounted with `compress` option, but it looks like by default it only compresses files and directories with the `+c` ("compression") flag explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

Per the current [wiki page on compression:](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression)

> Can I set compression per-subvolume?
>
> Currently no, this is planned. You can simulate this by enabling compression on the subvolume directory and the files/directories will inherit the compression flag.

Also per the [wiki page:](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression)

> Compression to newly written data happens:
>
> 1. always -- if the filesystem is mounted with -o compress-force
> 2. never -- if the NOCOMPRESS flag is set per-file/-directory
> 3. if possible -- if the COMPRESS per-file flag (aka chattr +c) is set, but it may get converted to NOCOMPRESS eventually
> 4. if possible -- if the -o compress mount option is specified
>
> Note, that mounting with -o compress will not set the +c file
> attribute.

So if you don't want a directory compressed, you have two options:

- Be on a filesystem (not just subvolume) mounted without the compress
  option, and have no properties set to compress it.
- Be on a filesystem with the compress option set (but not forced), and have the
  property of NOCOMPRESS set.

The chattr attributes currently only *enable* compression (with the +c flag). There is no flag to *disable* compression. The X flag does something different.

If you want to disable compression, you should use the `btrfs property` command which can turn compression on/off:

`btrfs property set <file> compression none`

This should apply to all newly written data to the file/directory.

Also from the wiki:

> Note, in kernel versions before v5.14 you could disable compression by passing an empty string instead of explicitly mentioning none or no. Since kernel version 5.14, an empty string resets to default behavior.

So setting compression to "" on your system should have disabled compression, but on more recent kernels you should pass none/no instead.

Also [per the wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression#How_can_I_determine_compressed_size_of_a_file.3F) there is no builtin tool to check the compression of data, but you can use [compsize](https://github.com/kilobyte/compsize) to check on newly written data.

Answer (score 1):

> I should be able to use chattr +X /var

e2fprogs define no such attribute as `X` (uppercase x), see [chattr.1](https://man.archlinux.org/man/chattr.1.en#ATTRIBUTES) for a full list of supported attributes.

The following steps can be used to force decompress /var and prevent btrfs from compressing any new writes. To be on the safe side, it's best to proceed after the /var filesystem is unmounted.

```bash
mv /var /var.old

# or use `btrfs subvolume create /var` if it was originally a subvolume
mkdir /var

# Tell btrfs that we don't want compression here
# chattr +m /var can be used as well
btrfs property set /var compression none

# Do not leave out the `/.` after /var.old !
cp -a --reflink=never /var.old/. /var

# Please make sure that the copy is working before removing /var.old
rm -rf /var.old # or `btrfs subvolume remove /var` for subvolume
```

You can check if compression is disabled with

```bash
compsize -x /var
```

The above command should report `TOTAL      100%`